# Product with 0 inventory should be shown in PDP but must not get selected on clicking on them,

Tags: magento-1.9

I wanted the **different sizes** to be shown on the **PDP** of my website, but if the product has 0 inventory art the back end it should show a cross sign over it so that it clarifies that it cannot be selected 
eg: s=2m=1
l=0
xl=0

thus XL AND L size should show a cross on them making it visible to the users that the product is out of stock.

Please check and revert soon.my magento version is 1.9.3

Regards